# How to use a default value for named parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that takes an object as a parameter like this:

```
const someFunc = ({ a }) => { <do something> }
```

I call the function like this:

```
a = 'some value'
someFunc({ a })
```

But sometimes, I need to call the function without passing `a`. In that case, I need to use a default value for `a`. How can I add a default value for a key inside an object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the default value for the object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667622/set-the-default-value-for-the-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

```js
const someFunc = ({ a = "foo" }) => {
   console.log(a);
}
someFunc({}); // "foo"
someFunc({a: "bar"}); // "bar"
```

**Update**
If you also want to have `a` as default to `"foo"` without passing any argument, you need to set a default parameter *also* for the object that contains `a`. Something like:

```js
const someFunc = ({ a = "foo" } = {}) => {
   console.log(a);
}
someFunc(); // "foo"
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined`

Comment: Well, you're edit didn't work, my code was working assuming what the OP asked (that "a" wasn't passed, not the object that contains "a"). Your edit should have added any object to the `someFunc()` call. If the OP want to call `someFunc` also without passing anything, the function signature should include that.

Comment: I didn't edit anything. I made a snippet and called your own function. `Your edit should have added any object to the someFunc() call` No, that's precisely the point, OP wants a default parameter if none is passed, so...

Comment: You add the function call in a way wasn't intended to be called: of course it doesn't work. This is "editing the (running) code", you didn't merely add the snippet. Any code won't work if called improperly. The OP, literally, wrote: _"I need to call the function without passing *a*"_. And `a` is the property, not the object. And that I replied to. If he *meant* the whole object, I edited my answer to cover that scenario too. But it's not what he wrote.

Answer (score 3):

ES6 accepts default values for parameters :

```js
const someFunc = ({a} = {a : 6}) => { 
  console.log({a})
}
someFunc({ a : 3 })
someFunc()
```

Comment: That works! Also, what if I want to call it like `someFunc({})`? This might be required if I have multiple keys inside the object.

Comment: JS is loosely typed, you can pass any object to the function if it's defined like this : `someFunc = (obj = {a : 6})`. If the answer worked for you, please don't forget to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const someFunc = ({a, b, c ,d} = {a:10, b: 12, c:3, d:4}) => {
   console.log(a, b, c ,d);
}
someFunc()
```

Remember that this code wont actually work in IE.

Here is the workaround for IE:

```js
    var someFunc = function someFunc() {
    var _ref = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : {
       a: 10
    },
    a = _ref.a;

    //here starts the function
    console.log(a);
};
someFunc();
```

Comment: That works! Also, what if I want to call it like `someFunc({})`? This might be required if I have multiple keys inside the object.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not work if I call it like `someFunc({})`. Here I am passing an empty object instead of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const someFunc = ({ a }) => { 
 typeof a === 'undefined' 
 ? a = 'some default'
 : a = a;
 console.log(a);
}

a = 'some value';
someFunc({ a });
someFunc({});
```

Comment: What if a is a Boolean and has value of false? It would be better to check if a is undefined.

Comment: This is an odd way to write a ternary assignment. Usually I'd do `a = a === undefined ? "default" : a` rather than (ab)use assignment expressions. Could you provide an explanation for why this is preferable to the existing answers?